# How to Connect Xamarin.forms PCL with SQL Server directly?

Tags: sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to know how to connect Xamarin.Forms PCL with SQL Server directly. I know accessing the database directly will not be secured. But that's not problem in my situation. I need to access database directly from Xamarin.Forms. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have developed an app with Xamarin.Forms PCL.

Comment: You need to use Web API (or some other intermediary) to transfer the data from the DB to your app.

Comment: Any direct method?? Without using Web API.

Comment: You could connect directly to your database using the database's connection string, but it is highly not-recommended, because it opens up the possibility of database corruption. For example, if a mobile phone sends an `Insert` instruction to the database, but midway through sending the instruction, the mobile device loses it's internet connection (e.g. goes through a tunnel or enters a cellular dead-zone), the `Insert` instruction doesn't properly complete and now your database is corrupted....

Comment: .... Instead, use an API! Connect the API to your database using the database's connection string. Using an API, our mobile device sends the `Insert` request to the API, and the API sends the `Insert` instruction to the database. Now, if our mobile device loses its internet connection after sending the request to the API, the API will still execute the `Insert` command successfully, avoiding any database corruption.

Comment: Here is a sample app I created that shows how to create an API and connect it to a SQL Database using Xamarin.Forms + Azure: https://github.com/brminnick/XamList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question, use [Entity Framework Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) and a connection string, directly to your database. That will enable you to connect directly to it.

Now, I'm going to spend the rest of this answer, why you shouldn't do this

- You are giving a remote, unknown, complete stranger, complete, direct access to your database. Even if it's in a separated network, with completely trusted users, and not on the app store, you are still opening your database up to potential security breaches.
- It is likely over an unreliable mobile connection or wifi. It will fail and drop out, a lot.
- It will be incredibly slow
- If you want to move that SQL server later or update, you will break every single client out there, while you send an update for your app.
- You won't be able to easily add any logic, in between, to improve performance, or add business logic as needed.
- Database corruption, another important and likely to occur scenario, as mentioned by Brandon above.

What you need to do.

- Create a web api. It's easy to setup one with WebAPI with dotnetcore
- The API connects to the database, the mobile client connects to the API.
- Add authentication to your API.

And I go into some more detail in [Connecting to a remote database](https://xamarinhelp.com/connecting-remote-database-xamarin-forms/) here.

Comment: Thanks. I will use WEB API rather than Direct method. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348767/xamarin-forms-pcl-android-debugging-hangs-on-httpclient if you know.